# Laravel работа с маршрутами

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация

Как в Laravel можно получить класс по наименованию роута, который его должен обрабатывать, НЕ текущего роута?
Предполагаю решение: взять список всех маршрутов и перебором найти, но мне не нравится такой подход. Должен быть статический метод, которым можно получить информацию о

Например, есть такой маршрут:

```
Route::get('/office/{id}', "OfficeController@PageInfo")->name('office_info_page');
```

Где-нибудь в хелпере я знаю имя этого маршрута `office_info_page`. Мне нужно вызвать метод method() этого класса например, `OfficeController::method()` зная только имя роута.

В документации нашёл только сведения о текущем роуте.

Answer (score 1):

Например так, если правильно понял задачу. Создаёте конфиг в котором будут храниться маршруты и контроллеры которые их обрабатывают таким образом(для примера):

```
//routes.php (например)
...
'callback_routes' => [
    'office_info_page' => Foo::class,
     ...
    'route_name' => Bar::class
]
```

Далее в `OfficeController` в методе `method` (можно выделить в родительский класс) пишите что-то типа такого:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class OfficeController {
...
    public function method()
    {
        $route = Route::current();
        $name = $route->action['as'] ?? null;
        if (!$name) return response('Укажите имя маршрута');
        $className = config('routes.callback_routes.'.$name);
        $classCallback = new $className;
        ...
        return ...;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ковырялся и нашёл ещё способ:

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route)
{
  if(isset($route->action['as']) && $route->action['as'] == 'office_info_page')
  {
    dd($route->action['controller']);
  }
}
```

Решение не качественное, сломается, если в роуте прописать "as" по другому

Comment: Способ тот же только более неэффективный. Обратите внимание на мой ответ выше. Каким образом у Вас поменяется as? когда заменяете name в роуте то и проверка меняется соответсвенно. Больше он никак не поменяется. Специально показал Выше как формируется конфиг. Создаёте его и указываете все имена классов всех маршрутов которые должны обрабатывать запрос помимо основного контроллера. Не понятно зачем этот способ нужен Вам в принципе